Kudu api - Delete directories which are not empty using powershell
I am trying to delete directories and their multiple subdirectories which have multiple files in azure webApp kudu api using powershell.
try {
$maxDepth = 6  # Maximum depth to explore nested directories

$webApps = Get-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName "RG1"

foreach ($webApp in $webApps) {
    $webAppName = "wa1" #$webApp.Name
    # Generate Kudu API URL for log files
    $kuduApiUrl = "https://${webAppName}.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/"

    # Retrieve publishing profile for the Azure Web App
    Write-Output "Retrieving publishing profile for $webAppName..."
    $publishingProfile = Get-AzWebAppPublishingProfile -ResourceGroupName "bossvg-dev" -Name $webAppName

    # Parse publishing profile XML to get credentials
    [xml]$publishingProfileXml = $publishingProfile
    $publishingUserName = $publishingProfileXml.publishData.publishProfile[0].userName
    $publishingPassword = $publishingProfileXml.publishData.publishProfile[0].userPWD
   
    # Convert credentials to base64
    $base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes("${publishingUserName}:${publishingPassword}"))
    Write-Output "Retrieving log files from $webAppName..."
    
    # Define function to recursively delete directories and their contents
    function DeleteDirectoryContents {
        param (
            [string]$directoryUrl,
            [int]$depth
        )
        
        Write-Output "Deleting directory contents: $directoryUrl, Depth: $depth"
        
        $directoryContents = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $directoryUrl -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic $base64AuthInfo")} -Method GET

        # First, delete files within the lowest-level subfolders
        foreach ($item in $directoryContents) {
            $itemName = $item.name
            $itemUrl = $directoryUrl + $itemName

            if ($item.mime -eq "inode/directory") {
                if ($depth -gt 1) {
                    # If it's a directory and not at the minimum depth, recursively delete its contents
                    DeleteDirectoryContents -directoryUrl $itemUrl + "/" -depth ($depth - 1)
                }
            } else {
                # Delete the file
                $deleteResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $itemUrl -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic $base64AuthInfo"); "If-Match"= '*'} -Method DELETE

                # Check if the deletion was successful
                if ($deleteResponse) {
                    Write-Output "Deleted file: $itemUrl"
                } else {
                    Write-Error "Failed to delete file: $itemUrl."
                }
            }
        }

        # Next, delete the current directory if it's not the top level
        if ($depth -ne $maxDepth) {
            # Delete the directory
            $deleteResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $directoryUrl -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic $base64AuthInfo"); "If-Match"= '*'} -Method DELETE

            # Check if the deletion was successful
            if ($deleteResponse) {
                Write-Output "Deleted directory: $directoryUrl"
            } else {
                Write-Error "Failed to delete directory: $directoryUrl."
            }
        }
    }

    # Get log files using Invoke-RestMethod
    $logFilesToProcess = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $kuduApiUrl -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic $base64AuthInfo")} -Method GET

    Write-Output "Number of log files to process: $($logFilesToProcess.count)"
  

    foreach ($file in $logFilesToProcess) {
        $sourceFileUrl = $file.href
        $destinationFileName = $file.name
        $deleteUrl = $kuduApiUrl + $file.name

        # If it's a directory, delete it and its contents
        if ($file.mime -eq "inode/directory") {
            Write-Output "Deleting directory and its contents: $deleteUrl"

            # Delete the directory and its contents
            DeleteDirectoryContents -directoryUrl $deleteUrl + "/" -depth $maxDepth
        } else {
            # Invoke the delete operation for files
            $deleteResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $deleteUrl -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic $base64AuthInfo"); "If-Match"= '*'} -Method DELETE

            # Check if the deletion was successful
            if ($deleteResponse) {
                Write-Output "Deleted file: $deleteUrl"
            } else {
                Write-Error "Failed to delete file: $deleteUrl."
            }
        }
    }
}
} catch {
    Write-Error "An error occurred: $_"
    throw "Error occurred. Script execution terminated."
}


error Message:  Invoke-RestMethod : {"Message":"Cannot delete
directory. It is either not empty or access is not allowed."}

Example of one drive and its subdirectories
C:\home\LogFiles>dir /s /w 85b7f6_19_03_27_03_31_58
Volume in drive C is Windows
Volume Serial Number is 2685-DC57
Directory of C:\home\LogFiles\85b7f6_19_03_27_03_31_58
[.]              [..]             [http]           [W3SVC355609351]
eventlog.xml
1 File(s)         12,261 bytes
Directory of C:\home\LogFiles\85b7f6_19_03_27_03_31_58\http
[.]       [..]      [RawLogs]
0 File(s)              0 bytes
Directory of C:\home\LogFiles\85b7f6_19_03_27_03_31_58\http\RawLogs
[.]                       [..]                      85b7f6-201903300024.log
85b7f6-201904012036.log   85b7f6-201904041648.log   85b7f6-201904071301.log
85b7f6-201904100915.log   85b7f6-201904130528.log   85b7f6-201904160130.log
7 File(s)     35,911,439 bytes
Directory of C:\home\LogFiles\85b7f6_19_03_27_03_31_58\W3SVC355609351
[.]            [..]           fr070476.xml   fr070477.xml   fr070478.xml
fr070479.xml   fr070480.xml   fr070481.xml   fr070482.xml   fr070483.xml
fr070484.xml   fr070485.xml   fr070486.xml   fr070487.xml   fr070488.xml
fr070489.xml   fr070490.xml   fr070491.xml   fr070492.xml   fr070493.xml
fr070494.xml   fr070495.xml   fr070496.xml   fr070497.xml   fr070498.xml
fr070499.xml   fr070500.xml   fr070501.xml   fr070502.xml   fr070503.xml
fr070504.xml   freb.xsl
30 File(s)      9,869,528 bytes
Total Files Listed:
38 File(s)     45,793,228 bytes
11 Dir(s)               0 bytes free

Take a look here, be careful since this script removes everything https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/2103
